# Unity3D New Input System - How to configure sensitivity of mouse ONLY on a composite binding?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

In my game, you can move the camera either by using WASD or by holding a mouse button and moving the mouse. Similar for rotation and zoom - they all have both keyboard and mouse controls.

That's easy enough to set up in the new input system. I have set up three actions (move, rotate, zoom) and given them both mouse and keyboard bindings.

However, I'd like to configure sensitivity of the mouse. People have set their mice up differently. I know how to add a processor to the mouse binding to give mouse and keyboard different sensitivities using a scale processor.

I can't figure out how to access that processor in code to change it based on a player configuration option. I want to change ONLY the mouse scale processor, NOT the keyboard one - keyboard is just 1/0 so it's the same for everyone, but mice are configured differently and I want players to set their own MOUSE sensitivity.

I've read the documentation, various tutorials, the closest I found was this, but it refers to the whole action, not an individual binding: https://gamedevbeginner.com/input-in-unity-made-easy-complete-guide-to-the-new-system/#ineractions_and_processors

Comment: `keyboard is just 1/0 so it's the same for everyone` .. as a user I still would want to be able to adjust sensitivity for both tbh otherwise it sounds like people using the mouse have an advantage against keyboard input

Comment: In genet couldn't you use completely different axes and rather apply the sensitivity in your code and then forward the input to the same method for handling and applying it in your game? This way you can have different multipliers for the different input types/axes

Comment: @derHugo it's not a multiplayer game, so advantage isn't an issue and I don't want to burden players with a config option 99% won't use. Yes, I could define different controls for the same use and solve the issue in code, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of the input system which is there to abstract those things.

Comment: `I don't want to burden players with a config option 99% won't use` .. these users will simply leave it at the default values ;)

Comment: @derHugo I know. It's about cluttering up the settings UI. There would be three sliders there that (almost) everyone just leaves alone. Better to leave them out. Anyway, that's all not related to my actual question.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work

Comment: @frankhermes copy&paste problem. fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the Unity forum pointed me in the right direction and posted a working solution that I could adapt to work for me:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-configure-sensitivity-of-mouse-and-keyboard-individually-on-the-same-action.1221417/